# Gem::LoadError Specified 'mysql2' for database adapter

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using ruby and rails in window 7. I am create a basic blog application which is given by ruby and rails site

I have create db connection with mysql like this

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: message
  username: root
  password: 
  pool: 5
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
  timeout: 5000
```

Now i am getting error. I have search but not get so many ans but that is not related to window :(

Please help me, how can create connection with db

```
Gem::LoadError
Specified 'mysql2' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'mysql2'` to your Gemfile.
```

Tthis

Comment: Can you post your gem file?

Comment: Did you add `gem 'mysql2'` to your Gemfile and run `bundle install`, as the error suggests?

Comment: Right now i have not install gem, I don't have knowledge how to do this ? I have write down this -- gem “mysql2″, “~> 0.3.11″ -- in gem file Now i don't know what do next :(

Comment: Hi Kirti Thorat I have write down this in gem file -- gem “mysql2″, “~> 0.3.11″ -- what to next how to install bundle ?

Comment: Then just run bundle install as @KirtiThorat suggested

Comment: Go on command prompt. Change directory to your `application folder`. And run command `bundle install` on terminal.

Comment: sorry i get error --an error occurred while installing mysql2, and bundler cannot continue make sure that gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.15 , succeeds before bundlind :(

Comment: help me how can do this :(

Comment: Refer to this link https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2#windows